# Spring JPA Repository Hibernate - EntityGraph load ManyToMany Collection

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Suppose i have an entity like

```java
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "with-keys",
    attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(Substitution_.KEYS),
    }
)
public class Substitution {

  @ManyToMany
  private Set<Key> keys;

  private boolean disabled;
}
```

now when i use the repository method `findAll(Pageable pageable)` with a page of let's say 50 elements and then let jackson serialize the entities, hibernate will fetch the `keys` for each Substitution individually, which results in 1 + 50 SQL statements...

So i annotate `findAll` with `@EntityGraph(value = "with-keys")`.

But then hibernate tells me `HHH90003004: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory` and still loads all entites individually although it already joined the keys.

Why does it even try to load it all into memory, this can have a huge performance impact which might not even work if there are too many entities?

Why can't the Spring JPA Repository do a second query after the initial page of Substitutions and load all of their keys at once?
For example with the following SQL and then map the keys to the substitutions by id:

```sql
select skr.subst_id, key.*
from subst_key_relation skr,
join keys key on key.id = skr.key_id
where skr.subst_id in :substitutionIdsInPage
```